# Custom solution intern .NET Core CLI tool

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-cli

Is it possible to create a custom .NET Core CLI tool, which is just part of the solution and not distributed via nuget?

I tried to reference the custom tool in the project.json's tools section like a normal dependency, but that didn't work at all.

---

The project.json referencing the custom tool:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "buildOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": true
    },

    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
            "type": "platform",
            "version": "1.0.0"
        },
    },

    "tools": {
        "MyTool": "1.0.0-*"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "netcoreapp1.0": {
            "imports": "dnxcore50"
        }
    }
}
```

And the project.json of the tool itself:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "buildOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": true,
        "outputName": "dotnet-mytool"
    },


    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
            "type": "platform",
            "version": "1.0.0"
        }
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "netcoreapp1.0": {
            "imports": "dnxcore50"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not possible. You cannot have references to tools projects. More details here:

- https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/1215
- https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2469

Comment: Do you have any other idea how the scenario where a tool has to generate code for a library in the same solution (based on an external definition file) could be done alternatively? Possibly in some clean and portable way.

Comment: Maybe write a standalone application and run it as a precompile script? The   app will generate the code that could be consumed when building the project (if this is your scenario).

Comment: This was my first approach, but the spec rarely changes, so there is no need to run it at every compile. I guess for the moment it is manual calling the generator until the tools work internally too :)